# Running SQL Server Express on Windows 11 with 10 client PCs

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, windows-11, sql-server-express

I'm setting up a machine that will be running a SQL Express 2019 server and having 10 client PCS.

I think I'm correct with this that Windows 10 or 11 will be fine for that number of devices connecting both to SQL and SMB shares, as from what I can see Windows 10/11 supports 20 connected devices for things like File and Print Sharing.

I've used this setup previously for very small 4 or 5 machine networks and it has been fine.

I don't particularly want to go down the router of Windows Server 2019/2022 as they don't need a DC.

I think I'm doing my usual of overthinking things and creating confusion in my mind.

My question is does the license for Windows 10 or 11 allow running SQL Server Express for 10 or 12 client devices?

Comment: So what exactly is your question? SQL Server Express isn’t intended to be used in a production environment but it can be in certain locations. You don’t need a domain server to accomplish what you want but it also might not be possible with Express due the limitations of that specific edition of SQL Server.

Comment: @Ramhound   

My question is:  Will windows 10 or 11 suffice for running a network of 10 to 12 devices running SQL Server Express?

The limitations on Express are fine for the DB in question, ,my concern is the number of devices connecting to it.

Thanks.

Comment: The limits of Windows edition won’t affect your ability to connect to a specific version of SQL Server. Limits surrounding SMB is something else entirely. Technically speaking you can any edition of SQL Server on non-server editions of Windows

Comment: A good answer will require many more parameters regarding your network and the 10-12 computers. On paper, this will work. In reality, only testing will tell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, A windows 10/11 machine will support 10 devices.

The [license agreement](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/UseTerms/Retail/Windows/11/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_11_English.htm) for desktop versions of Windows do have a limit of 20 total connections for the OS services below, but it does not apply to SQL server/ODBC connections:

> (iii) **Device connections.** You may allow up to 20 other devices to access the software installed on the licensed device solely to use the following software features for personal or internal purposes: file services, print services, Internet information services, and Internet connection sharing and telephony services on the licensed device.

All current editions of SQL Server itself allow a maximum of [32,767](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-connections-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) simultaneous user connections.